# How do I select rows from my MySql table that occurred according to a max date?

Tags: mysql, max

I’m using MySQL 5.5.37.  I have a table with the following structure …

```
mysql> desc event;
+------------------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field                  | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+------------------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| ID                     | varchar(32) | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
| EVENT_ID               | varchar(32) | NO   | UNI | NULL              |       |
| ORGANIZATION_ID        | varchar(32) | NO   | MUL | NULL              |       |
| DATE_PROCESSED         | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
| EVENT_DATA             | longtext    | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
+------------------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

I would like to select the row corresponding to the last event processed for each organization.  I only need the organization_id and the event_id for each organization.  However, I’m not sure how to build this query.  I have this so far

```
mysql> select organization_id, max(date_processed) from event group by organization_id
```

But I’m not sure how to use this to deduce the event_id.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check against the `event_id` column like

```
Select e.event_id, e.organization_id,
xx.maxdate, xx.maxevent
from event e join ( 
select organization_id, 
max(date_processed) as maxdate,
max(event_id) as maxevent 
from event 
group by organization_id) xx on e.organization_id = xx.organization_id
and e.event_id = xx.maxevent;
```

Comment: Depending on the nature of event_id, it is possible there will be no rows that satisfy that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT organization_id, event_id 
FROM `event` 
WHERE (organization_id, date_processed) IN (
   SELECT organization_id, max(date_processed) 
   FROM `event` 
   GROUP BY organization_id
)
;
```

Be wary of the `event` table name, it is a keyword in more recent versions of MySQL.